# Kconfig - compiling kernel module

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules, drivers

I stumbled over this [site](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap#USBTV007_EasyCAP) about USB video grabber under Linux, I'm trying to compile the code found [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/media/usb/usbtv). I have read about makefiles but this one confuses me, cause it's so short:

```
usbtv-y := usbtv-core.o \
    usbtv-video.o

obj-$(CONFIG_VIDEO_USBTV) += usbtv.o
```

I wanted to write now my own makefile. What I want to know now is, what the `Kconfig` file is for and how to use it. I have a hard time finding more information about how to use it. Can someone enlighten me please?

Here's the Kconfig file:

```
config VIDEO_USBTV
        tristate "USBTV007 video capture support"
        depends on VIDEO_V4L2
        select VIDEOBUF2_VMALLOC

        ---help---
          This is a video4linux2 driver for USBTV007 based video capture devices.

          To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the
          module will be called usbtv
```